# PHP parse function call with parameters from string

Tags: php, parsing

What is the best way to parse a string containing a function call with parameters in PHP so that I have the function name and the parameters with their correct types. Example:

```
$string = "ask('Do you want to continue?', ['yes', 'no'])";
```

I don't want to directly call that function, so `eval` is not an option. I want to do something based on the function name and use the parameters with their correct types. Is there an easy way in PHP?

I expect something like this as a result:

```
$name = 'ask';
$parameters = ['Do you want to continue?', ['yes', 'no']];
```

Comment: Nothing in PHP per se. You'd need to code that yourself. Have you tried anything so far?!

Comment: https://github.com/nikic/php-ast should be able to parse it to an AST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the arguments to be parsed to an array structure, you would still need to use `eval` (with all the precautions taken to ensure that the content is safe).

This code also assumes the format is as expected, i.e. it represents a valid function call, and the closing parenthesis is the final non-blank character:

```
$string = "ask('Do you want to continue?', ['yes', 'no'])";

$parts = array_map("trim", explode("(", substr(trim($string), 0, -1), 2));
$parts[1] = eval("return [$parts[1]];");
```

`$parts` will be:

```
[
    "ask",
    [
        "Do you want to continue?", 
        ["yes", "no"]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use one good library to parse PHP code.
that is some example of that kind of library

```
use PhpParser\Error;
use PhpParser\NodeDumper;
use PhpParser\ParserFactory;

$code = <<<'CODE'
<?php

function test($foo)
{
    var_dump($foo);
}
CODE;

$parser = (new ParserFactory)->create(ParserFactory::PREFER_PHP7);
try {
    $ast = $parser->parse($code);
} catch (Error $error) {
    echo "Parse error: {$error->getMessage()}\n";
    return;
}

$dumper = new NodeDumper;
echo $dumper->dump($ast) . "\n";
```

https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser

Comment: Could you add how would you convert the $ast to the actual needed output.